# Is it possible to create textured SKSpriteNode without a texture and set it some time later?

Tags: sprite-kit

Is it possible to create a SKSpriteKitNode without a texture, add it to the scene and then set a texture to it?

I have tried creating node this way:

```
SKSpriteNode *node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture: nil];
```

and then adding a texture:

```
 node.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:image];
```

but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SKSpriteNode* node = [SKSpriteNode node];
```

and then set the texture later on, but be sure to update the size:

```
node.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:image];
node.size = node.texture.size;
```

Alternatively, you can create a sprite node with color or texture and just set its `hidden` property to `YES`, or change its scale to 0.0 or change its size to 0 width/height or change its alpha to 0.0. So many things you can do to not show a (sprite) node ... ;)